# Install Geonode on Manjaro (Based on Arch Linux)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, maps, manjaro

### I'm trying to install Geonode on Manjaro. I've also seen that it can be installed with docker but it's new to me and I can't find any tutorial that works for me. My Linux distribution is Arch Linux, for which the package manager is pacman and not apt-get as it is the case in Ubuntu, is it possible to install Geonode on Arch Linux?

I have also used this command triying to install it on postgres:

> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker
>   compose.override.localhost.yml up --build

But I get an error like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toQD5.png)

> ERROR: for nginx4geonode  Cannot start service geonode: driver failed
>   programming external connectivity on endpoint nginx4geonode
>   (e0ef6b5b7bd9ad55b195996232e7cb3ce90408379c587f3c0240b6bf06fef544):
>   Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address
>   already in use
>
> ERROR: for geonode  Cannot start service geonode: driver failed
>   programming external connectivity on endpoint nginx4geonode
>   (e0ef6b5b7bd9ad55b195996232e7cb3ce90408379c587f3c0240b6bf06fef544):
>   Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address
>   already in use ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the
>   project.

---

And this command shows the same error:

> docker-compose up --build

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgCdg.png)

Comment: Docker Compose usually doesn’t print out the text “enter image description here”.  Can you replace these links with the actual text of the error message you’re getting?  Including enough source code to reproduce the issue (for example, a fragment of your `docker-compose.yml` file and your image `Dockerfile`) is essential too.

Comment: Hi David I clone the geonode repository from Git-Hub, my docker compose is allowed on this link:  $ git clone https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode.git

Comment: I do not think Arch Linux will currently work. I would suggest to start the stack with docker. Eiter the official or SPC. docs.geonode.org shows how.